# $\max_{\{X_N\}}{\frac{\mu^2(X_N)}{\mu^2(X_N)+\sigma^2(X_N)}}$ for $X_N=\{x_1,...,x_n\},x_i\in \mathbb{N}^+,\exists(i,j):x_i\neq x_j$

Tags: statistics, optimization, standard-deviation, means, upper-lower-bounds

### Short version of the question

Consider
\begin{equation}
g(X_n)=\frac{\mu^2(X_N)}{\mu^2(X_N)+\sigma^2(X_N)}\\
X_N=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\},n>1,\forall i:x_i\in \mathbb{N}^+,\exists(i,j):x_i\neq x_j
\end{equation}
where $\mu,\sigma$ are mean and standard deviation of a random sample $X_n$, respectively.

I would like to find the smallest $U$ so that $g(X_n)<U<1$.

---

### Detailed version of the question

For finding the complexity of a classifier that I have recently proposed, I should find the root of the following function, regarding $z$
\begin{align*}
&f(z)-g(X_n),\\
&g(X_n)=\frac{\mu^2(X_N)}{\mu^2(X_N)+\sigma^2(X_N)}\\
&z\in(0,\infty),f(z)\in(0,1),\lim_{z->0^+}{f(z)}=0,\frac{d}{dz}f(z)>0\\
&X_N=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\},\forall i:x_i\in \mathbb{N}^+,\exists(i,j):x_i\neq x_j
\end{align*}
As it can be seen, due to the properties of $X_n$, we have $0<g(X_n)<1$.

However, if $g(X_n)$ has an upper bound like $U$ (i.e. $g(X_n)<U<1$), then I can find the computational complexity of solving $f(z)$ with no problem. But if $g(X_n)$ is free to tend $1^-$, finding the computational complexity becomes problematic.

However, it seems to me that because of the properties of $X_n$ such as having only positive integers and necessarily including at least two distinct members, the upper bound $U$ exists for $g(X_n)$.

Can anyone, please, provide a hint for finding such upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

Such $U$ does not exist. For any given $y_0$ there exist an $X_N$ where $\mu(X_n)\geq1$ and $\sigma^2(X_n)<y_0$.